# Spring Data Elasticsearch use BigDecimal as id

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

For some reason I want to use a BigDecimal type value as id. But when running, I got a error "Unsupported ID type class java.math.BigDecimal".

I found following codes in ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java.

```
protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
    if (isQueryDslRepository(metadata.getRepositoryInterface())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("QueryDsl Support has not been implemented yet.");
    }
    if (Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(metadata.getIdType()) || Long.class.isAssignableFrom(metadata.getIdType())
            || Double.class.isAssignableFrom(metadata.getIdType())) {
        return NumberKeyedRepository.class;
    } else if (metadata.getIdType() == String.class) {
        return SimpleElasticsearchRepository.class;
    } else if (metadata.getIdType() == UUID.class) {
        return UUIDElasticsearchRepository.class;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported ID type " + metadata.getIdType());
    }
}
```

According to the codes, I can only use Integer, Long or Double as Number Key. But I have problem if I change my id type to Long or String.

Is there a way I can use BigDecimal as id?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **BigDecimalBridge**

```
@SortableField
@FieldBridge(impl = BigDecimalBridge.class)
@Field(normalizer = @Normalizer(definition = "lowerCaseNormalizer"), store = Store.YES)
@Column
private BigDecimal quantity;
```

Comment: When answering an old post, it would be helpful if you could provide some context to your answer rather than just code, as it might make it more useful to others.